# How to Copy complete structure of a table with data from one database table to another databse table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a sql query to copy data with structure from production table of ONLINEBTREKDB database to production table of Archive database.

I tried this query

select * into Archive.dbo.Production from ONLINEBTREKDB.dbo.Production p

but problem is I am able to copy the table schema and data but not able to copy constraints(PK)
Any Help?

Comment: Try using DAC import/export. It should keep data and schema with all keys

Answer (score 0):

First you remove primary from destination table and then use query to copy data from source table to destination table.